# Ros publisher message type for arrays

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone please tell me what message-type to use in publishing the following array?:

```
[
  ['/turtle1/color_sensor', 'turtlesim/Color'], 
  ['/client_count', 'std_msgs/Int32'], 
  ['/rosout', 'rosgraph_msgs/Log'], 
  ['/rosout_agg', 'rosgraph_msgs/Log'], 
  ['/connected_clients', 'rosbridge_msgs/ConnectedClients'], 
  ['/all_topics', 'std_msgs/String'], 
  ['/turtle1/cmd_vel', 'geometry_msgs/Twist'], 
  ['/turtle1/pose', 'turtlesim/Pose']
]
```

I'm reacquainting myself with ROS and learning the basics as I modify a basic talker to publish the array above instead of a string. I have consulted [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs) but I'm having difficulty figuring out which of those message types to use, if any.

publisher = rospy.Publisher('/all_topics', **???**, queue_size=1)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358121/ros-publisher-message-type-for-arrays/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2020-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) on 2020-07-27**:
I'm not sure, if you can use the std_msgs as it is, but maybe can custom-define your own msg? Something like this `StringMultiArray.msg`

```
std_msgs/MultiArrayDimension[] dim
std_msgs/String[] data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no predefined message to do this easily. You can do what @praskot suggested, or go one of many other ways.
(Note, you can always check the other [common_msgs](https://wiki.ros.org/common_msgs?distro=noetic) if you want to use one of the generic types ones)

In general, it is, however, advised to add [semantic meaning](https://discourse.ros.org/t/suggestions-for-std-srvs/1079/10) to messages and thus stay away from the `std_msgs` package as much as possible. See also #q255674.

All in all, you have to create your own message type. The following are just some ways to do that, in addition to what @praskot suggested:

`KeyValueLists.msg`

```
std_msgs/String[] keys
std_msgs/String[] values
```

`Dictionary.msg` (using a message from the [diagnostic_msgs](https://wiki.ros.org/diagnostic_msgs?distro=noetic) package)

```
diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue[] items
```

of course, you could that create yourself too, if you don't want to depend on the `diagnostic_msgs` package

`KeyValueString.msg`

```
std_msgs/String key
std_msgs/String value
```

and thus:

`StringDictionary.msg`

```
KeyValueString[] items
```

(obviously, the names are free to choose...)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2020-07-30**:
Thanks, I'm working on your suggested solution